# How to create serially numbered variables in workspace?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I was wondering how I can use a for loop to create multiple matrix when given a certain number.

Such as If 3 was given I would need three matricies called: C1, C2 and C3.

```
k = 3
for i = 1:K
    C... = [ ]
end
```

Not sure how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing coming in mind is the `eval` function mentioned by Dennis Jaheruddin, and yes, it is bad practice. [So does the documentation say:](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html)

> **Why Avoid the eval Function?**
>
> Although the eval function is very powerful and flexible, it not
>   always the best solution to a programming problem. Code that calls
>   eval is often less efficient and more difficult to read and debug than
>   code that uses other functions or language constructs. For example:
>
> MATLAB® compiles code the first time you run it to enhance performance for future runs. However, because code in an eval
>   statement can change at run time, it is not compiled.
>
> Code within an eval statement can unexpectedly create or assign to a variable already in the current workspace, overwriting existing
>   data.
>
> Concatenating strings within an eval statement is often difficult to read. Other language constructs can simplify the syntax in your
>   code.

The "safer" alternative is the function [**`assignin`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html):

The following will do exactly what you want:

```
letter = 'C';
numbers = 1:3;

arrayfun(@(x) assignin('base',[letter num2str(x)],[]),numbers)
```

I know cases where you need to create variables likes this, but in most cases it is better and more convenient to use **cell arrays** or **structs**.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use a cell array:

```
k=3
C=cell(k,1)

for t=1:k
  C{t}= rand(t)
end
```

If each matrix is of equal size, you would probably just want a three dimensional matrix rather than a cell array.

You now have one cell array,but can access the matrices like this:

```
C{2} %Access the second matrix.
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without making a Cell array. To have them separate? 
So I end up with
C1 = [ ];
C2 = [ ];
And so forth

Comment: @user3575908 There are ways, but all ways to do this in a loop would be ugly (using `eval` which is pretty bad practice typically). So I won't explain how to do that unless you can give me a good argument why you would really need it.

Comment: Okay, if I then wanted to concatenate data to matrix 1, how would I access that. This doesn't seem to work?

C{1} = [C{1}; Output2(i,:)];

Where output is simply my data, and i is iterating through

Comment: @user3575908 In general you could  just use concatenation like you mentioned, try `[C{1}; C{1}]` Just make sure the things that you try to concatenate exist and have the proper size.

Answer (score 0):

The use of eval is almost inevitable in this case:

```
k = 3;
for i = 1:k
        eval(sprintf('C%d = [];', i));
end;
```

Mind you that generating variable names for data storage rather than indexing them (numerically -- see the solution of Dennis Jaheruddin based on cell arrays -- or creating a dynamic `struct` with named fields that store the data) is almost always a bad idea. Unless you do so to cope up with some weird scripts that you don't want to / cannot modify that need some variables already created in the global workspace.