# Use a counter for nonindexed variables and putting them in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell

I have 20 cities in Matlab.

```
city1='arad'   
...  
city20='neamt'
```

My question is, how to use a counter as 'i' for call my cities and put them all in an array.

I have tried these:

```
    function [city,neighbor,list]=m()  
    main; //referred to my cities name in main.m  
    for i=1:20 //i used a loop   
    city=cityi  // what i whises is city1...city20 
    list=[city]// i want all cities in an array!  
    end
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What does main.m look like can you show us? And is it really a .m or rather a .mat file?

Comment: @Benoit_11 - To me it looks like it's just a MATLAB script that performs 20 variable assignments from `city1` up to `city20`.  I personally would have just saved them to a `.mat` file and loaded them in.  It's cleaner and when you load the `.mat` file in, you can save its contents into a variable and it would be a structure where you can dynamically access the fields using dynamic variable name accessing by constructing appropriate strings.

Comment: Yep  I was waiting for the OP to give details as I did not understand what he had in mind haha!I had dynamic field names in mind but without much details in the question that was hard to guess!Good idea with struct2cell +1!

Comment: Besides the two (very) good answers, you can find here more ideas- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038161/how-to-create-serially-numbered-variables-in-workspace

Comment: 'clc;clear;  
city1='Arad'  
[neighbor_name neighbor_distance straight_line_distance]=makeneighbor('Zerind',75,374)  
[neighbor_name neighbor_distance   straight_line_distance]=makeneighbor('Sibiu',140,253)  
[neighbor_name neighbor_distance straight_line_distance]=makeneighbor('Timisoara',118,329)

city2='Zerind'
[neighbor_name neighbor_distance straight_line_distance]=makeneighbor('Oradea',71,380)
[neighbor_name neighbor_distance straight_line_distance]=makeneighbor('Arad',75,366)
.
.
.
city20='Neamt'
[neighbor_name neighbor_distance straight_line_distance]=makeneighbor('Iasi',87,226)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid using `eval`, you can save all of your workspace variables that have `city` at the beginning of them to a temporary `.mat` file, then reload the `.mat` file by storing its contents into a variable.  This variable would essentially be a structure where each field is named according to the variables that you saved from your workspace.  Once you load this structure in, you can use [`struct2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html) to convert each structure field into a separate entry in a cell array.  As Kamtal has noted in his post, it is suggested that you put all of these in a cell array, especially since the length of each city will change per variable.

When you load in the `.mat` file, the way the structure fields are ordered should be numerically sorted, and so we don't have to worry about ordering anything.  If you are truly concerned, consider using [`orderfields`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/orderfields.html) to ensure that the fields are ordered numerically.... but I'm pretty sure this won't be a problem.

The end result will be a cell array that contains all of your cities.  Once you're done with this `.mat` file, you can delete it from your computer.

Assuming that you only want to save those variable names that start with `city` (i.e. `city1, ..., city20`) in your workspace, try doing this:

```
save('data.mat', 'city*'); %// Save the variables to a MAT file
data = load('data.mat'); %// Load them back into a structure that contains fields corresponding to the variable names
cellArray = struct2cell(data); %// Convert structure to cell array
delete('data.mat'); %// Delete the temporary file
```

`cellArray` will contain all of your cities indexed from 1 up to 20.  Therefore, if you want to access a particular city, simply do:

```
city = cellArray{idx};
```

`idx` is the city ID that you want to access.  Therefore, if you wanted to access `city15`, do:

```
city = cellArray{15};
```

Comment: Very nice trick.. +1 is nothing for it. This trick can come in handy!

Comment: @Kamtal - mer30 Kamtal jan!

Comment: @rayryeng
i have inserted my 20 cities before in main.m, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183944/romanias-cities-breadth-first-search-using-matlab, %you said kamtal 'jan', 'jan' is a persian word meaning 'dear' :D,

Comment: @sajadkhammar - I know what it means :) That's why I said it!

Comment: @sajadkhammar - By the way, if we have helped you, consider accepting one of our answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should put them in a `cell`

```
for i = 1 : 20
    eval(['A{',num2str(i),'} = city',num2str(i)]);
end
```

I don't see other choice but to use `eval`.

Comment: Yup... if the variable names are all individual like that, then you'd have to use `eval`.  I can't see any other method.

Comment: Kamtal, I wrote an answer that doesn't use `eval` if you're curious, but I had to temporary save the files to a `.mat` file, then reload them in so that it all gets converted into a structure, then used `struct2cell` to convert the structure into individual cell array elements